# Reverse order of elements on stack

Tags: java, stack

I have my exercise: reverse the order of elements on stack using one additional stack and some additional non-array variables. And what I have done:

```
public void reverse() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        stack1.push(stack.pop());
    }
    stack = stack1;
}
```

I used one additional stack (stack1) and where additional non-array variables could be used?

Comment: @duy-nguyen.se What you did is good enough. What else do you want?

Comment: According to the Java API documentation Stack should not be used anymore. Use a Deque instead. You can access both ends of a Deque.

Comment: @aventurin Thanks for your information.

Comment: Why are you throwing exception on empty stack? Reversing an empty stack just produces an empty stack: `if (isEmpty()) return;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void reverse() {
   Collections.reverse(stack);
}
```

Comment: I think he want to implement it himself without any predefined func.